# Otherwise redirectTo '/not-found' while keeping the previous URI

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've added a 404 page to my router. So here is my code:

**app.js**

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/not-found'
});
```

**error.js**

```
app.error = angular.module('CRM.Error', ['ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad']);

app.error.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    var routes = {
        '/not-found': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/error/views/not_found.html',
            controller: 'NotFoundController',
            page: {
                title: '404 Not found',
                name: 'notfound',
                require_auth: false
            },
            resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'CRM.Error',
                        files: [
                            'app/modules/error/controllers/not_found.controller.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    for (var path in routes) {
        $routeProvider.when(path, routes[path]);
    }

}]);
```

**not_found.controller.js**

```
app.error.controller('NotFoundController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    console.log($location);
}]);
```

It works well, my view is loaded.

Now I'd like to print a message such as *"Sorry, but the page [URL] that you are trying to view does not exist."*
But I'am on `/not-found` URI so I need to retrieve the previous URI.

I tried something in **app.js**

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
```

and

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
```

`current` gives me `/not-found` information, `previous` and `next` are `undefined`.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
// firing an event upwards
$scope.$emit('myCustomEvent', 'Data to send');

// firing an event downwards
$scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', {
  someProp: 'Sending you an Object!' // send whatever you want
});

// listen for the event in the relevant $scope
$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data); // 'Data to send'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use UI-router ? You must have some fix in the behavior of router. And previous state works correctly.

Replace the current, the normal, the standard method of routes.